# Repeated cross-validation for lambda and alpha with glmnet / glmnetUtils

Tags: glmnet

I used `mice` to create some multiply imputed datasets:

```
library(glmnetUtils)
library(mice)

nhanes <- mice::nhanes
imp <- mice(nhanes)
com <- complete(imp, "long")
```

Using `glmnetUtils`, it is possible to cross-validate for both alpha and lambda simultaneously:

```
nhanes$hyp <- factor(nhanes$hyp)
fit <- cva.glmnet(hyp ~ ., data = nhanes, alpha = seq(0, 1, 0.05), family = "binomial")
```

**Questions:**

- How could I run repeated cross-validation using `glmnetUtils`?
- How can I parallelise the process? My real training dataset has 71,200 observations and takes approximately four hours to complete one run of cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

To do parallel computation, you just need to follow the glmnetUtils manual. 
In your case, you can do something like the following.

```
numCores = detectCores(logical = FALSE) 
c1<-makeCluster(numCores)
fit <- cva.glmnet(hyp ~ ., data = nhanes, alpha = seq(0, 1, 0.05), family = "binomial",outerParallel=c1)
```